# Twitter Bootstrap add-on spans with input greater than requested column width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the following Bootstrap code to line up input fields on the same row. The appended strings I am using as units on the fields add width pass the two column span.

```
  <div class="row">
    <h5 class="span2">Temperature</h5>
    <h5 class="span2">Length</h5>
    <h5 class="span2">Weight</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span2">
      <div class="input-append">
        <input class="span2" type="text"><span class="add-on">&deg;C</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
      <div class="input-append">
        <input class="span2" type="text"><span class="add-on">m</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
      <div class="input-append">
        <input class="span2" type="text"><span class="add-on">kg</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Question: Is there a way to squeeze the width of the input field so that the field combined with the appended characters fit within the given column span?**

Also, I am repeating class="span*N*" frequently in the code which seems bloated. Any suggestions on DRYing that up would also be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `class="span2"` for your input fields, you can try `class="input-small"`
like

```
<div class="span2">
      <div class="input-append">
       <input class="input-small" type="text"><span class="add-on">&deg;C</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

This will squeeze the width of the input fields as desired by you..